# How to plot a graph in shiny app after a file has been uploaded

Tags: r, shiny

I have a really simple csv file.

```
> head(data)
  X Y
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 4
4 4 8
```

I am trying to create a shinny app dashboard that plots this data after the file has been uploaded.

This is what I have so far.

```
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250))
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)

  inFile <- input$file1
  data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But I am getting an error

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

From what I have read the read file needs to be reactive, and then that need to be called by the plot, but I am not familiar with the reactive concepts, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you watch these tutorials to get the basic idea of reactive programming with Shiny: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
data <- reactive({
  inFile <- input$file1
  if(!is.null(inFile)){
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
  }
})

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  req(data())
  plot(data()$X, data()$Y)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, with your suggestion the app runs now, but the graph before uploading the file shows an error  "Error:need finite 'xlim' values" and after I upload the file it changes to a different error "Error: need finite xlim values" but it does not show any plot

Comment: @JuanLozano I've just edited my answer. Does it work now ?

Comment: I made the changes, the first error is gone, but after I upload I get this error "Error:invalid argument type"